# Can't get ship to move after modifying ship speed in alien invasion

Tags: python

I can't get my ship to move after adding the ship speed in the settings. I identified that the problems has to do with the code self.rect.x = self.x under the Update method of the Ship class. If I comment it out, the ships is able to move, but when I uncomment the ship stops moving. Can't figure this problem out, followed the instructions of the book and don't know where I went wrong. Thank you.

```
import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

class AleinInvasion:
    """Overallclass to maange game assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Intialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
        self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship= Ship(self)

        #Set background color
        self.bg_color = self.settings.bg_color

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self._update_screen()


            #make the most recenlty drawn screen visible
            #pygame.display.flip()

    def _check_events(self):
        #watch for keyboard and moust events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)

    def _check_keydown_events(self,event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()

    def _check_keyup_events(self,event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = False 
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = False


    def _update_screen(self):
        """Updates images on the screen, and flip to the new screen"""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        

        #make the most recenlty drawn screen visible
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = AleinInvasion()
    ai.run_game()

 class Settings:
    """A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's settings."""
        # Screen Settings 
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230,230,230)
        
        # Ship settings
        self.ship_speed = 1.5
   

import pygame

class Ship:
    """A class to manage the ship"""

    def __init__(self,ai_game):
        """ Intialize the ship and set its starting postiion."""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        # Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Start each new ship at the bottom of the screen.
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom


        # Store a decimal value for the ship's horizontal position.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

        #movement flag
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        """Update the ship's postiion based on the movement flag"""
        #UPdate the ship's x value, not the rect
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.rect.x += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0: 
            self.rect.x -= self.settings.ship_speed

        #Update rect object from self.x
        self.rect.x = self.x

        

    def blitme(self):
        """ Draw the ship at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Comment: I'm confused. You set `self.rect.x += self.settings.ship_speed`, but then you immediately undo that change via `self.rect.x = self.x`, and now you're saying you don't know why the ship doesn't move. But you're explicitly undoing the movement. Did you mean to do `self.x = self.rect.x`?

Comment: Please try providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in accordance with stack overflow guidelines, as this will greatly help any reader answer your question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks @RandomDavis I see where I went wrong. Thanks! Still new to coding sorry for the confusion